# Using the component ion-datetime the information are displayed in two lines

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using IONIC framework for create an APP, but I have a little issue whit a "datetime" component the values are showed in two lines.

````
    <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>Datos de nacimiento</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime value="{{fechaNaci | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" display-format="YYYY MMMM DD"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>```

I expect the output should be displayed on the yellow rectangle instead of green one:

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLVr6.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I was checing the documentation about ionic and I found my issue I forget add and `ion-item` between `ion-list` and my `ion-label` something very simple.